VMWare Workstation 16 can't compile after Ubuntu 22.04 update
Another day, another break with my VMWare Workstation 16 after taking the latest Ubuntu 22.04 update. Upon updating, rebooting, and launching VMWare, it pops the typical process to recompile for the kernel changes. However, this time it's not trivial.
Here's my error.
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o] Error 255
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 make[3]: *** Deleting file '/tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/common/crosspage.o'
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/common/task.c:548:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘TaskGetFlatWriteableDataSegment’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605   548 | TaskGetFlatWriteableDataSegment(void)
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 In file included from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/./include/cpu_types.h:29,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/./include/modulecall.h:33,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:33,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:32,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:47:
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_defs.h:753: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605   753 | #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | 
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 In file included from ./include/linux/prandom.h:12,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/random.h:153,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/nodemask.h:98,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/list_lru.h:12,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/fs.h:13,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/highmem.h:5,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 ./include/linux/once.h:46: note: this is the location of the previous definition
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605    46 | #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)                                                   \
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | 
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 In file included from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:56:
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 ./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h: In function ‘random_get_entropy’:
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 ./arch/x86/include/asm/timex.h:12:24: error: implicit declaration of function ‘random_get_entropy_fallback’; did you mean ‘random_get_entropy’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605    12 |                 return random_get_entropy_fallback();
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       |                        random_get_entropy
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c: At top level:
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:703:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘Vmx86FreeVMDriver’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605   703 | Vmx86FreeVMDriver(VMDriver *vm)
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:736:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘Vmx86AllocVMDriver’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605   736 | Vmx86AllocVMDriver(uint32 numVCPUs)
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 In file included from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/./include/cpu_types.h:29,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/./include/modulecall.h:33,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:59:
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/./include/vm_basic_defs.h:753: warning: "DO_ONCE" redefined
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605   753 | #define DO_ONCE(code)                                                   \
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | 
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 In file included from ./include/linux/prandom.h:12,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/random.h:153,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/nodemask.h:98,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/mmzone.h:18,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/gfp.h:7,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from ./include/linux/slab.h:16,
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605                  from /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:37:
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 ./include/linux/once.h:46: note: this is the location of the previous definition
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605    46 | #define DO_ONCE(func, ...)                                                   \
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | 
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:2946:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘HostIFCheckTrackedMPN’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605  2946 | HostIFCheckTrackedMPN(VMDriver *vm, // IN: The VM instance
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3066:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘HostIFWritePhysicalWork’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605  3066 | HostIFWritePhysicalWork(MA ma,             // MA to be written to
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:3225:1: warning: no previous prototype for ‘HostIFStartTimer’ [-Wmissing-prototypes]
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605  3225 | HostIFStartTimer(Bool rateChanged,  //IN: Did rate change?
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o] Error 1
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-40-generic/Makefile:1926: /tmp/modconfig-g6MIPl/vmmon-only] Error 2
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
2024-08-26T13:35:37.365Z In(05) host-8605 make: *** [Makefile:117: vmmon.ko] Error 2


The Community has largely figured out how to fix this. In particular, nan0desu's fork provides updated Workstation. However for me this wasn't enough, the instructions from multiple places weren't complete. In the end this is what I had to do:

Update my Workstation 16 to the latest version. I was on 16.2.4. When I checked out nan0desu branch for 16.2.4, I got the same compile errors. Locating the workstation download took some searching. I came across this wonderful answer that brought me to the download packages that Broadcom has made difficult to find. I downloaded the Linux package and followed Broadcom's instructions to install.
sh VMware-Workstation-16.2.5-20904516.x86_64.bundle --console

Next I cloned the patched Workstation client at github.com/nan0desu/vmware-host-modules and switched to the workstation-16.2.5 branch. The build steps are simply make and then make install.

Now VMWare Workstation will launch, but the VMs do not. I got:
Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded.

This was fixed by sudo modprobe -v vmmon


Now it is working, although with a non-official client. Hopefully the official client will get fixed soon.
